# Swift Parse Query To Get All The People Whose Organization Matches The Logged In Users

Tags: swift, parse-platform

On our Parse DB we have a User class and an Organization class. There's an object in the User class that points to the Organization class. I want to be able to query for all of the users with the same Organization ID as the currently logged in user.

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Member")
            query.whereKey("organization", equalTo: PFUser.current())
            query.findObjectsInBackground {
                (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
                if let objects = objects as [PFObject]? {
                    self.memberObject = []
                    for object in objects {
                        self.memberObject.append(object)
                        self.member.append(Member(
                               id: object.objectId!,        
                               createdAt: object["createdAt"] as! String,
                               firstName: object["firstName"] as! String, 
                               lastName: object["lastName"] as! String, 
                               username: object["username"] as! String, 
                               email: object["email"]  as! String, 
                               role: object["role"] as! String))
                        print(self.memberObject)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                } else {
                    print("failure")
                }
            }
```

This is the query I currently have. So far it isn't pulling anything and nothing is being populated in the arrays. How can I check for what I'm checking for. Which is essentially to see if the logged in user shares a value with another user?

Comment: "I want to be able to query for all of the users with the same Organization ID as the currently logged in user." I think you forgot the .organization or ["organization"]:  query.whereKey("organization", equalTo: PFUser.current().organization)

Comment: Sadly .organization doesn't exist and ["orgnization"] didn't do anything.

Comment: Member class is your User class on "There's an object in the User class that points to the Organization class." ?

Comment: This line is very strange:  query.whereKey("organization", equalTo: PFUser.current()) you are trying check if the current user are in the organization field...

Comment: I have this now. Member was supposed to be User that was my mistake when I was filling this out. `let query = PFQuery(className: "User")
        query.whereKey("organization", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "organization")!)`. organization is a pointer to the class Organization each organization has an objectId I'm just trying to compare the current users against other users and return all of the ones with the same id.

Comment: It had to be `query = PFQuery(className: "_User" so I get the values but now I get exc_bad_instruction. Thanks for the help CCastro!

Comment: Try this: let user = PFUser.currentUser()   let query = PFQuery(className: "User") query.whereKey("organization", equalTo: user["organization"])

Comment: maybe u need  cast:    equalTo:(user["organization"] as! PFObject)

Comment: I finally figured it out. I had to empty the member array before it could append to it. I had `self.memberObject[ ]` but not `self.member[ ]` I appreciate your help!